# Nested ElseIf Statement doesn't trigger inside of For Each loop

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I am trying to figure out why my nested ElseIf statement will not trigger when looping through a column.
The loop exits prematurely without evaluating the nested ElseIf statement, causing the column to not be updated.
I understand if I change the nested ElseIf to a normal If, then it will work. But I want to know why.

Here is my data:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub test1()

Dim x As Range
For Each x In Range("B2:B11"):
    If x.Value = 0 Then
        If x.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Ford" Then x.Value = 1001
        If x.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Toyota" Then x.Value = 1002
        If x.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Honda" Then x.Value = 1003
    
    ElseIf x.Value = 1 Then
        If x.Offset(0, 1) = "California" Then x.Value = 2001

        ElseIf x.Offset(0, 1) = "New York" Then x.Value = 6001

    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without seeing your actual code. Please edit your answer to add a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, thought it was attached. It is now

Answer (score 4):

When you write an If-statement with a command after the `Then` in the same row, you have a one-line `If`-statement. Those If-statement needs no `End If`, they are "done" at the end of the line.
You can have an `Else`-branch on the same line (which makes it rather unreadable in the most of the cases), but you can't have an ElseIf on the same line.

So your last `ElseIf`-statement is not an else-branch to the California `If`, it is seen as another `ElseIf` to the first `If`-statement. It executed only if `x.Value = 0` was False and `x.Value = 1` was False (which is never the case with your data). Correctly indented, your code is

```
If x.Value = 0 Then
    If x.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Ford" Then x.Value = 1001
    If x.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Toyota" Then x.Value = 1002
    If x.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Honda" Then x.Value = 1003
ElseIf x.Value = 1 Then
    If x.Offset(0, 1) = "California" Then x.Value = 2001
ElseIf x.Offset(0, 1) = "New York" Then x.Value = 6001

End If
```

See your problem? The `New York`-Branch is never hit because x is always 0 or 1. You could either write (as you do for the car brands)

```
ElseIf x.Value = 1 Then
    If x.Offset(0, 1) = "California" Then x.Value = 2001
    If x.Offset(0, 1) = "New York" Then x.Value = 6001
End If
```

Or (I guess you tried that already)

```
ElseIf x.Value = 1 Then
    If x.Offset(0, 1) = "California" Then 
        x.Value = 2001
    Else If x.Offset(0, 1) = "New York" Then 
        x.Value = 6001
    End If
End If
```

Or use a Select-Case for the inner parts (this is how I would do it)

```
Dim x As Range
For Each x In Range("B2:B11")
    If x.Value = 0 Then
        Select Case x.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Case "Ford": x.Value = 1001
            Case "Toyota": x.Value = 1002
            Case "Honda": x.Value = 1003
        End Select
    ElseIf x.Value = 1 Then
        Select Case x.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "California": x.Value = 2001
            Case "New York": x.Value = 6001
        End Select
    End If
Next
```

NB: The colon at the end of your `For`-statement is superfluent. A colon signals that another statement follows on the same line.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and was exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: nicely explained

Answer (score 1):

Another approach replacing multiple `If` and `ElseIf` would be using `Select Case`, see modifed code below:

```
Sub test1()

Dim x As Range

For Each x In Range("B2:B11"):
    If x.Value = 0 Then

        Select Case x.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Case "Ford"
                x.Value = 1001                
            Case "Toyota"
                x.Value = 1002                
            Case "Honda"
                x.Value = 1003            
        End Select
                
    ElseIf x.Value = 1 Then

        Select Case x.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "California"
                x.Value = 2001                
            Case "New York"
                x.Value = 6001                
        End Select        
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```